# Justification Issues when aligning

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I am trying to cleanly add reference tags in the links I have on various e books and websites. In order to align them, I hit tab on the next lines of the link. The problem is the justification breaks when I do this. Need advice, thank you

[image]

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cLAXNuxo6ACpIndk3Y_V_R6f-RatXMGMreGoMpHONYA/edit?usp=drive_web (link to the word file)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MS WORD then at the top click on the icon and in the bottom you will file two option.Click on word options and go to the advanced tab.There is one column named as Compatibility,There you'll find layout options.Just search for

> Do full justification the way WordPerfect 6.x for windows does.

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: The only compatibility in File >> Options >> Advanced is "Compatiblity Options for"

Comment: Select your document and below of that you will find layout option.Just expand it and click on Do full justification